# rkhunter: prelinking hash function warning

Tags: linux, centos, rkhunter

We are using rkhunter to check to scan our server periodically. Server operating system is CentOS 6/7. But since last rkhunter update (to currently version 1.4.4) we getting following warning message:

```
[10:12:09] Performing file properties checks
[10:12:09] Warning: Checking for prerequisites               [ Warning ]
[10:12:09]          All file hash checks will be skipped because:
[10:12:09]              This system uses prelinking, but the hash function 
                        command does not look like SHA1 or MD5.
```

But we had prelinking all with:

```
/> prelink -a --md5
```

Anybody knows how I can prevent the message or what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Delete the `/etc/prelink.cache` file. Run the prelink rebuild with `/etc/cron.daily/prelink`. Then run `rkhunter --propupd`.

Then doing a `rkhunter -c` showed clean.

From:
https://sourceforge.net/p/rkhunter/mailman/message/35131677/

Update:
CentOS has since added an upgrade that removes the comment mark from the line HASH_CMD=sha1sum in the rkhunter.conf file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the message came back a few days later.  Trying to decide if it is better to disable pre-linking or change the rkhunter.conf file to use SHA1 again which was the previous default.  Upgrading the default to SHA512 is where the problem originates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this indefinitely by running the following for each file listed in the Warning. For example, /bin/grep was as follows:

```
prelink /bin/grep
```

Then, running:

```
rkhunter --propupd
```